# Changing React Native Debugger port (Windows 10)

Tags: android, windows, react-native

I'm using port `8088` instead of `8081` for my Android emulator ([using these instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html)), running on Windows 10.

The React Native Debugger is now throwing a `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` error, which I suspect is because it's trying to connect to port `8081` (photo below).

How can I set the Debugger to use port `8088`?

[image]

[image]

Note: I cannot use port `8081` because my school requires McAfee antivirus which uses the port. I promise, I wish I could just use `8081`

Edit: Added emulator error

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

It appears that [this is a known issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9935). Luckily, there is a [pull request out to fix it](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/12095).

In the meantime, I ended up stopping the program that was on port `8081` using Windows Services (search for 'services' in the Windows 10 search bar).

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in react-native 0.42 and above.